# Twitter login with Playwright

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, playwright-python

I'm new to Playwright, and I can't figure out how to get this working. I can enter my userID just fine, but then can't find the right code to click on the "Next" button. Here's one (of many) things I tried:

```
from playwright_stealth import stealth_async
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

with sync_playwright() as pw:
    browser = pw.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1200, "height": 1080})
    page = context.new_page()

    page.goto("https://twitter.com/login")  # go to url
    page.fill('input[type="text"]', 'unsername_here')
    page.locator('button:text("Next")').click()
```

Why doesn't this click the "Next" button and how can I get it to work? When I run the code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 12, in <module>
    page.locator('button:text("Next")').click()
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 15436, in click
    self._sync(
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 104, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_locator.py", line 148, in click
    return await self._frame.click(self._selector, strict=True, **params)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_frame.py", line 489, in click
    await self._channel.send("click", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 61, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 461, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\twitterSentiment\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 96, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("button:text(\"Next\")")
============================================================
```

I'm running version 1.32.1 of Playwright.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be enough:

```
page.locator("//span[text()='Next']").click()
```

You are trying to locate a button when actually is not a button, is a span, I just changed the locator in order to make it work with xpath.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That works. It also turns out that it IS a button, though, with the span as a part of it. As I was able to get it to work with:
page.get_by_role("button", name="Next").click()